# При нажатии на кнопку "Bot Info" не отправляется текст

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Бот не реагирует на клавишу. Ошибок не выдает , при нажатии никакой реакции нет. Код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

TOKEN = ''

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):

    markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

    item1=types.KeyboardButton("English")
    item2=types.KeyboardButton("Українська")
    item3=types.KeyboardButton('Руский')

    markup.add(item1, item2, item3)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello, {0.first_name} ".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Select the language to use the bot:".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def movUK_message(message):
    if message.text == "English":
                
        markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

        item1q=types.KeyboardButton("Info")
        item2q=types.KeyboardButton("Exchange rate")    

        markup.add(item1q, item2q)
        
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Menu".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Select a function:".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['Info', "text"])
def moUK_messag(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Version: Alpha 0/0/3")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на декоратор хэндлера

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['Info', "text"])
```

Почему вы тут указываете content_types? Вам нужно создать хендлер который будет ловит конкретно текст "Info", делается это вот так:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Info")
```

Указывая content_types вы говорите хендлеру какой ТИП сообщений ловила функция, т.е. голосовое сообщение, документы и т.д.

Comment: так же не реагирует